# Extra space at the top of Keyboard - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I don't get what is the problem with my design. Here is the code,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".emi.advanced_emi.AdvancedEmiActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/adlayout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_advanced_emi" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/adlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/adheight"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/c5" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The content_advanced_emi has a scrollview which has edittexts and some other views. Here is a part of code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/main_emiadvance"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<LinearLayout

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/commontext"
            android:text="Loan Amount "
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <EditText
            android:background="@drawable/enabled_edittext"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/loan"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:maxLength="15"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:hint="Rs."/>

    </LinearLayout>
    ....</ScrollView>
```

My problem is when the keyboard is opened, there is an extra gap (I guess, it is 50 dp) above the keyboard. How Can I solve it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: THat could be the candidates view, part of the keyboard.  It looks like its about the right size.  If so putting the NO_SUGGESTIONS flag on the field might get rid of it.

Comment: may be its your `adlayout` `RelativeLayout` that u have added at the bottom

Comment: @GabeSechan But if I set android:visibility="gone" to the adLayout, extra space is not visible.

Comment: @NileshRathod But I have set the background color as Violet for adLayout. But in the screenshot , That is not there.

Comment: @JyotiJK Then it is the adLayout, and you don't have it set to violet like you think you do.

Comment: @GabeSechan please check code. I have used `android:background="@color/c5"`

Comment: @JyotiJK That sets it to whatever is in your colors.xml file with the name c5.  Which we have no idea what that is.

Comment: @JyotiJK why don't you share your whole layout with question

Comment: @GabeSechan I posted a gif file. I need someone to help me. Not to confuse everyone. Please check it.

Comment: @NileshRathod I added part of a code cuz it is huge.

Comment: @JyotiJK added an answer, with an example how to hide/show the `adlayout` dynamically.

Answer (score 5):

I can't say what that extra space is, although the comments make some good suggestions. I can, however, show you a way that you can determine the nature of that space.

There is a very handy tool in Android Studio called the "Layout Inspector." This tool will allow you to look into an emulator or device to take a peek at the layout that is displayed.

The layout inspector is invoked from the "Tools" menu:

[image]

In the "Choose Process" dialog, pick your process. Here it is the process for "MyApplication."

[image]

The layout is displayed along with an image of the screen. You can click on various parts of the tree or the layout itself to see what's what. If you see your blank space here, you should be able to determine it's nature.

[image]

However, if you do not see your space, you will need to delve a little deeper. To look at the keyboard, invoke the layout inspector again (Tools->Layout Inspector) and select the process that holds the keyboard. For me, it is `com.google.android.inputmethod.latin` but it may be different for you.

[image]

Here we can see the candidates list that sits atop the keyboard. If you see your space here, then it is the candidates list or something else connected to the keyboard.

[image]

So, this is not a solution, but it should help get you on track.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir :) . May be it is the adLayout. Because if I hide it, there is no problem. But I don't know why the color is changed if it is the adLayout. I will check it. Once again Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it's that one `RelativeLayout`, with `layout_gravity="bottom"` and `layout_height="@dimen/adheight"`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/adlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/adheight"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/c5" />
```

would suggest to hide the `adlayout`, when the keyboard is not hidden:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (getHeight() > MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)){
        this.mBottomAdLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } else {
        this.mBottomAdLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```